# keras: model for learning with two input sequences and one scalar target value

Tags: python, neural-network, sequence, keras, preferences

I'm trying to implement this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03741 utility/preference learning approach in keras. The problem:

- xTrain: 2 input sequences ,yTrain: binary value
- The DNN only maps (single) input vectors to numeric values

To be more precise:

- DNN: f(x)=y
- t1 and t2 are sequences of vectors
- Loss-function: cross_entropy(sigmoid(sum_t1(f(x_t1))-sum_t2(f(x_t2))),1)

The question: How do i implement that ?

My current approach is to use a TimeDistributed network with flattened output. The input is a concatenation of both sequences. (WIP code below) But it think this is a really bad way and there has to be something better ?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Masking(mask_value=0.), input_shape(2000,inputDims)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(64)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(64)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))
model.add(Flatten())

model.compile(loss=customLoss,
              optimizer=Adam(),
              metrics=['mse'])

def customLoss(y_true,y_pred):
    y_pred = K.reshape(y_pred, shape=[2,1000])
    y_pred = K.sum(y_pred, axis=1)
    y_pred = K.sigmoid(y_pred[0]-y_pred[1])
    y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, epsilon, 1.0 - epsilon)
    loss = K.binary_crossentropy(y_pred, 1)
    return loss
```

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem with your network is. What are you trying to improve? Does it work? Have you tested it?

Comment: I still have a few bugs, but i think it will work. My problem is, that i need call the network on sequences. However, during prediction time, i only have single vectors - hence i have large 0-padded sequences. Furthermore, the length of sequences is differing greatly and it is difficult to determine the max length in advance. Hence, i would prefer something like calling the network for each vector (in the sequence) independently and save the activations for a later/manual gradient calculation.